# What happens to resistor when it "breaks" due to over-current or over voltage?

Tags: resistors

What happens to resistor when it "breaks" due to over-voltage or over-current?

Does it short or Open? or it merely ends up outside of specification?

Comment: Depends on what type it is.

Comment: It normally opens up when it breaks or increases in resistance, no chance of short really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything can happen, but *most* seem to go open circuit. You can buy 'fusible resistors' that are guarranteed to fail open circuit.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be a lone voice in the wilderness saying that under overloads that don't involve kilovolts metal film resistors and wirewound resistors tend to behave like a fuse (but not a guaranteed fuse) and some metal-oxide-film and some wirewound (eg. rectangular ceramic type) resistors may be guaranteed to act as a fuse.

**However** types involve **carbon** such as composition and carbon film resistors can arc at relatively low voltages (such as mains voltage) and the entire resistor becomes a **glowing ceramic rod** that ends up being lower resistance than it started. It's called carbon tracking.

I'm **not** suggesting anyone try this, hear me, but if you do, note that low value 'carbon film' resistors are often actually metal film. I don't remember where the transition was for 1/4-W resistors, but below 100 ohms, I think. It's not something they feel they need to disclose because even a low end metal or alloy like pure nickel will outperform the tempco of carbon (it is just unsuitable for high resistances, as carbon is unsuitable for very low resistances).

Answer (score 1):

The most common failure mode I have seen in resistors is that they open up. When too much current flows through the resistor (which can be caused by over-voltage as well) it heats up the material, causing it to melt. When it melts it acts like a fuse, breaking the circuit. If only slightly too much current flows through it it could change its resistance, either increasing or decreasing, but ultimately it will most likely fail open. I have never seen a failed resistor that was shorted.

Comment: What LED?? The OP asked about resistors.

Comment: :facepalm: I still had the previous question I read stuck in my head. I meant resistor, I just typed LED by accident. The answer is the same, just replace "LED" with "resistor".